# Unite Testing for Encoding/Decoding Algorithm

Tags: java, unit-testing, encoding

I have a function that encodes and decodes ASCII character images. My encode function reads a file and then creates a byte array to hold the image data. I was wondering what unit tests would be appropriate?

The purpose of the algorithm is to encode an image of ASCII characters in order to create a space efficient transport format. I create an encode function that holds, on odd elements, a count of each character followed by the actual character. My decode function uses this array to reprint the original image. I am asked to create test unit, but I have never used test units and was wondering what a test unit would look like in this case. Also suggestions on improving my algorithms are welcome.

Comment: A unit test for such a case is actually quite simple. Use a known, hard-coded input, encode it, check that it produces the output it should. In writing the algorithm, maybe you'll find some edge cases (like an empty image, or an invalid one), wite a test for that, too. Do exactly the same for the decoding, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: This type of expected value makes [Approval Tests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Java) a good fit. Typical unit tests have the expected values hard-coded into the test source code. Approval testing allows you to keep expected values as external data (under revision control, of course) that is easy to change as your expectations evolve with your code.

Comment: Would approval tests allow me to check that my code outputs the original image? For example, if I input an .txt file into encode(), then decode() it, how could I check that an ASCII image equals the original using the unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference about unit tests. It's long but worth reading.
[Unit Test in Java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)

Going back to your question you first need to make sure if your function or class is testable. A testable function is one which has its dependency passed in as argument of function. For example:

```
//Testable code
public class Animal{ 
    public Dog createDog(Type breed, Food prefreedFood, int age)
    {
        if(breed && food && age > 0)
        {
             Dog myDog = new Dog(breed, prefreedFood, age);
             return myDog;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Non testable code:

```
//Non testable code
public class Animal{ 

    public Dog createDog()
    {
        if(obj.breed && obj.food && obj.age > 0)
        {
             Dog myDog = new Dog(obj.breed, obj.prefreedFood, obj.age);
             return myDog;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this example I have written a createDog function in both ways one is testable and the other is not. If you try and test the testable function you can easily do it as following.

```
//Test case
Type breed = new Type("BullDog");
Food food = new Food("Best Dog food");
int age = 5;
Dog myBullDog = new Dog(brred, food, age);
assertEquals(myBullDog, createDog(breed,food,age)); //should return true
```

Whereas looking at the second class and function which has the dependency of an object it is very likely that the object which is used to retrive information is not being initialized at the time of test. Thus making it impossible to write test case.
Following the two code snippets testable and non testable respectively. Third code snippet is test case. You can find more info about writing test cases using assertFalse, assertTrue etc on the provided link. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I have my encode and decode methods under the same class, would my unit tests be written in the main method of that same class?

Comment: A good approach would be to create a different class for your tests. You can run the test class using JUnit. You will see the response in console of your tests.

Comment: Here is a good introductory link about [JUinit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/)

Comment: Thanks. I see that JUnit is good for verifying primitive types. For my decode method, I would want to verify that the image it prints is the original image. How can I do this?

Comment: As you have mentioned in your question "My encode function reads a file and then creates a byte array to hold the image data". I believe your encode function return this byte array. So in your test case you can create this byte array using something like byte[] encoded = encodeMethod(image);. You have also mentioned that your decode method reprints the original image thus I am assuming if you have written a testable code it should return decoded value in form of an image. The test case can be simply written using JUnit API assertEquals(picture, decodedValue);. It should return true.